# Twitter Streaming API - tracking exact multiple keywords in exact order

Tags: twitter, twitter-feed

I'm just beginning to play with the Twitter Streaming API.

If I specify

```
$sc->setTrack(array('just bought from'));
```

This will correctly pull only tweets that have all 3 keywords - but doesn't maintain the order.

1) I want the keywords to appear in the same order like

```
"I just bought apple from itunes"
```

but the above also returns tweets like

```
"I bought some apples and just removed them from the bag"
```

2) Is there a way to specify the exact words say "NBA basketball" with nothing in between - in the sense I dont want tweets like this to be returned

```
Watching basketball on NBA tv
```

I just want tweets which contain the exact phrase to be returned like

```
I love watching NBA basketball
```

3) Also is there a way to specify negative keywords

Any tips if this is possible.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the answer to all three questions is no.  The general recommendation is to do this post processing on your side.  The negative keyword is something that's been asked for quite a bit, but currently we don't have a scheme that would let us support this in a scalable way