# Twitter streaming API: track for exact phrase

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I want to listen to streaming API and track for exact phrases, [this post from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769154/twitter-streaming-api-tracking-exact-multiple-keywords-in-exact-order) say NO, you can't track an exact phrase, but I ask again in case anybody has fresher news. Is it possible yet?